# Trapping a Cancel in a JavaScript Confirm Prompt?

Tags: javascript, confirm

Something's not working this morning and I'm pretty sure it's my brain. I've got a form that tracks changes to a field under certain conditions:

-If the status = Draft, do nothing.
-If the status = Approved, prompt user to ask if they are sure they want to make the change.
-If they click 'OK', it should call the process that records the change.
-If they click 'Cancel' it should do nothing.
-If the status is anything other than draft or Approved, don't prompt but call the process that records the change.

I had the code recording changes in non-draft status, but after I added the ==true to the end of the confirm statement, everything stopped working.

```
var stat = $('#status').text(); 
var parms = just a bunch of parameters i'm passing to the url below;

if (stat=='(Draft)'){
//do nothing
}
else if (stat !== 'Approved' && stat!== '(Draft)'){
var url = webDbName + '/(CreateOTChangeRecordOnChange)?OpenAgent' + parms;
        $.get(url, function(data) {
            $('#tableBodyChanges').html(data);
});
}

}
else if (stat == 'Approved' && confirm('You are changing the hours on a request that has already been approved. This will send a notification to the department director. Proceed?')==true) {
  var url = webDbName + '/(CreateOTChangeRecordOnChange)?OpenAgent' + parms;
        $.get(url, function(data) {
            $('#tableBodyChanges').html(data);
                                });
} else {
//do nothing                                });
}
```

Comment: You have an extra `}` before the last `else if` block

Answer (score 0):

It is working, but you could just ommit the `== true` because it already is a "if-able boolean"

```js
if(confirm("test?")){
   console.log("confirmed1");
}else {
   console.log("notconfirmed1");
}

<!-- or the other way arround -->

if(!confirm("test?")){
   console.log("notconfirmed2");
}else {
   console.log("confirmed2");
}

<!-- it should also work the way you posted as well -->

if("foo" == "foo" && confirm("test?") == true){
   console.log("confirmed3");
}else {
   console.log("notconfirmed3");
}
```

Comment: Agree - it should work as I've got it, but doesn't. :(

Comment: than i´d say variable `stat` has contents you dont expect, you should also debug it and look at it